# HTTP in simple terms

Tags: http, web-deployment

I came across the term HTTP. I have done some research and wanted to ensure that I correctly understood the term.

So, is it true that HTTP, in simple words, a letter containing information in the language that both client and server can understand.

Then, that letter is sent to the server thanks to TCP/IP which serves as a car that takes that letter to the server.

Then, after the letter is delivered to the server, the server reads the content of the letter and if it is GET request, the server takes the necessary data and ATTACHES that data to the letter and sends back to the client via again TCP/IP. But if it was POST request then the client ATTACHES the DATA to the letter and sends it to the server so that it saves that data in the database.

Is that true?

Comment: HTTP is more than just client and server setup; it is a way for communication of computers on the internet to communicate. You might like to check out the RFCs describing the protocol for the complete picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it is true.

However, the server can decide what to do if it is a GET or POST or any other request(it doesn't need to e.g. append it to a file).

I will show you some additional information/try to explain it in my words:

TCP is another communication protocol protocol. It allows a client to open a connection to a server and they can communicate afterwards.

HTTP(hyper text transfer protocol) builds up on TCP.

At first, the client opens a connection to the server.

After that, the client sends the HTTP Request. The first line contains the type of the request, the path and the version. For example, it could be `GET / HTTP/1.1`.

The next part of the request contains the Request parameters. Every parameter is a line. The parameters are sent like the following: `paramName: paramValue`

This part of the request ends with an empty line.

If it is a POST Request, query parameters are added next. If it is a GET Request, these query parameters are added with the path(e.g. `/index.html?paramName=paramValue`)

After rescieving the Request, the server sends a HTTP Response back to the client.

The first line of the response contains the HTTP version, the status code and the status message. For example, it could be `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`.

Then, just like in the request, the response parameters are following. For example `Content-Length: 1024`.

The response parameters also end with an empty line.

The last part of the response is the body/content. For example, this could be the HTML code of the website you are visiting.

Obviously, the length of the content/body of the response has to match the `Content-Length` parameter(in bytes).

After that, the connection will be closed(normally). If the client to e.g. request resources, it will send another request. The server has NO POSSIBILITY to send data to the client after that unless the client sends another request(websockets can bypass this issue).

GET is meant to get the content of a site A web browser will send a GET request if you type in a URL. POST can be used to update a site but in fact, the server can decide that. POST can be also used if the server doesn't want query parameters to be shown in the address bar.

There are other methods like PATCH or DELETE that are used by some APIs.

Some important status codes (and status messages) are:

- `200 OK` (everything went well)
- `204 No content` (like ok but there is no body in the response)
- `400 Bad Request` (something is wrong with the Request)
- `404 Not found` (the requested file(the path) was not found on the server)
- `500 Internal server error` (An error occured while processing the request)

Every status code beginning with `1` is related to inform the client of something.

If it is starting with `2`, everything went right.

Status code beginning with `3` forward the client to another site.

If it starts with `4`, there is a error on the client side.

Codes starting with `5` represent an error that occured on the server side.

Comment: hey:D thank you for your kind answer, honestly, I have done truckload of research and it says that HTTP is a protocol which is a set of rules. Then, I found out that on POST request we send data to server and what is the relationship of a set of rules with data. To relieve my confusion, I had to turn HTTP into a letter:D. In reality, is HTTP a kind of an object which is understood by both client and server? Or?:)

Comment: I've added it to my answer.

Comment: and HTTP is just a communication protocol how to e.g. transfer files that needs to be understood by both client and server..

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a network protocol that establishes a connection with the server over a network (or the Internet) and allows two-way communication. The HTTP will traffic inside this TCP tunnel. TCP is a very useful protocol that helps keep things sane, it ensures data packets are read in the correct order and that packets that went missing during transmission are sent again.

Sometimes there will be another protocol layer between HTTP and TCP, called SSL. It is responsible for encrypting the data that traffics over TCP, so that it is transmitted safely over unsafe networks. This is know as HTTPS, and is just HTTP but using this additional layer.

Although almost always true, HTTP doesn't necessarily uses TCP. UPnP requests use HTTP over UDP, a network protocol that uses standalone packets instead of a connection.

HTTP is a plain text protocol, meaning it's designed in such a way that a human can understand it without using any tools. This is very convenient for learning.

If you're using Firefox or Chrome, you can press Ctrl-Shift-C to open the Developer Tools, and under the Network tab you will see every HTTP request your browser is making, see exactly what's the request, what the server answered etc, and get a better view of how this protocol works.

Explaining it in details is... too extensive for this answer. But as you will see it's not that complicated.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, upvoted+. But what confuses me is that yeah HTTP is a protocol which is a set of rules but I also found the infor saying HTTP is a language that both client and server can understand. If it is true, then how can "a set of rules" be equal to language, I mean, rules, as we know, is when we are told DO this and Don't do that.

Comment: @QQQQQ A communication protocol establishes a set of "rules" that both peers understand so that they can communicate. Just like in English, you have to know syntax, verbs, conjunctions etc. in order to speak and understand others speaking it. That's all that "protocol" means, it's a very broad term. HTTP has it's own syntax, and the request must be organized in a standardized way so that the server understands your request, and likewise the answer must be standardized as well so that the Browser knows what the server is saying.

Comment: @QQQQQ To be more specific, the request includes a "method", the file path, HTTP version, in the first line, (ie `GET /index.html HTTP/1.0`) and each subsequent line is a HTTP Header, in format `Header: Value`, and then you send an empty line to indicate you're done with the request. If you send anything different to that, it's not HTTP, and the server wont understand the request.